# Declined off-topic flag for migrated question

Tags: discussion, flagging

I have flagged this question as off-topic

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/celebrity-images-for-non-commercial-purposes

which, as you can see, was migrated to law.SE. My flag was declined; the question is obviously off-topic, or it wouldn't be migrated to another site. Why was this flag not helpful? Shouldn't it be accepted in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologized to Vincent within minutes of doing it when I realized he had declined your request. My exact words to him:

[image]

It was a debate even in my head. But my conclusion was it was off-topic but I see how someone, Vincent or otherwise could think differently. "Hey I'm designing a website is it okay to use this celebrity image in a composition?" would have been on topic. So it was kinda a fine line but I saw it more as a theater or legal question since it made no effort to indicate any sort of design intent just taking the image and displaying it.

But, had I realized Vincent already declined your flag then I wouldn't have undermined him and migrated it. I just didn't realize until after that there was a rejected flag on it.

Comment: You also migrated it after I wrote my answer (on Vincents suggestions) but before I posted it :P

Comment: I get it, it just seemed odd the flag was declined even though the question was migrated, I was trying to get how the system works

Comment: Now I remember, indeed. I declined @Luciano 's flag because this is something that a graphic designer should and could know.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the review history, the question *wasn't* closed through review. So you flag *was* declined. The question was migrated by someone else just under an hour later, by which point your flag had already been dealt with (assuming it was your flag that put it in the queue and you didn't flag it later).

Just a victim of human nature. Different reviewers, different outcome. If you'd have flagged half an hour later your flag probably would have been accepted.

Comment: silly humans : -)